# How can I remotely (via web services) determine date format of SharePoint 2003 site, for use in Versions.asmx returned XML?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, locale, regional, date-format

The GetVersions() call to the Versions.asmx web service in SharePoint 2003 returns a localised date format, with no way of determining what the format is. It's the site regional setting of date format, but I can't find a way to get even that out of SharePoint 2003. Locally, it looks like SPRegionalSettings can be used (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spregionalsettings.aspx) but what about a web service version of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the parameter that asks for the values in UTC is not supported for this call. I've just had to look for a month greater than 12 and use that as the hint to switch date formats. It'll mess up some dates, but I can't see a way around that. The code is at http://sourceforge.net/projects/splistcp/ if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, it isn't available. However, you can specify a query option to specify that you want the values returned in UTC:

http://www.sharepointblogs.com/pm4everyone/archive/2006/10/03/sharepoint-2003-querying-with-gmt-datetime.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, that parameter is not supported for this call. I've just had to look for a month greater than 12 and use that as the hint to switch date formats. It'll mess up some dates, but I can't see a way around that.